# Swift Metal MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I try to develop something on Metal iOS and receive the following error:

Code:

```
let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
```

Error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I'm on 
xcode 9.4.1

iOS SDK: 11.4

Architecture: arm64 armv7 armv7s

Can someone please help.

Comment: Have you tested it on real device?

Comment: No, I didn't test on device

Comment: Test it on device, it will not work on Simulator.

Comment: @aBilal17 Ok, I'll try. Is it possible to make it work in the simulator?

Comment: Shouldn't it by default access the Mac GPU when running on simulator?

Comment: Device means hardware device, simulator is not a device.

Comment: @aBilal17 Okay thank you :)

Comment: @aBilal17 Yep, waiting for countdown :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test it on real device iPhone or iPad, it will not work on Simulator.

Comment: It will now work one the simulator. Metal **will work on the simulator** in **iOS 13** and tvOS 13 simulators only when running on macOS **Catalina (10.15)** or later. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57912423/4833705

Answer (score 0):

It works on the simulator, but I have macOS `11.1` and I still encountered this problem.

In my case, the problem I found was that the `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()` result needs to be explicitly assigned to an `MTLDevice` variable, before passing it to the metalView.

This works:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var metalView: MTKView {
        return view as! MTKView
    }
    var device: MTLDevice!
    var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        metalView.device = device
        metalView.clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        metalView.delegate = self
        commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()
    }
    }
}
```

If we try to assign it directly to `metalView.device`, it throws the error:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        metalView.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        metalView.clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        metalView.delegate = self
        commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()
    }
```