# MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice returning nil on iOS 13 Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, metal, ios13, metalkit

I am using Xcode 11 GM Seed (11A419c). When I run Metal code on iOS 13 simulator and try to access metal device created using MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(), it returns nil. How is Metal supposed to run on simulator without this device? Is there any setting in XCode to fix it? I have Macbook Pro retina 2012 model running Mac OS 10.14.6 if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metal is available in iOS 13 and tvOS 13 simulators only when running on macOS Catalina (10.15) or later. This is documented in the [Xcode 11 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes).

Comment: Can you also please look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57834241/ciimage-display-mtkview-vs-glkview-performance