# Metal view's currentDrawable is nil in iOS simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, metal

`CAMetalDrawable` in `MTKView` is `nil` in when running on the iOS simulator. So I can't render on screen...

Using Xcode 11 GM, with Metal support in the simulator.

Any idea why [`metalView.currentDrawable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtkview/1535971-currentdrawable) would be `nil`?

**Update:**

Solved, using macOS Catalina with the new iOS 13 simulator.

Comment: Are you setting the deployment target to iOS 13?

Comment: What is the value of `metalView.device`?

Comment: `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()` returns `nil` on an app with deployment target of iOS 13, tho my framework with the code has a deployment target of iOS 11...

Comment: this must be why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57912423/4586652, I need Catalina...

Comment: Correct, Metal support in Simulators requires Catalina.